# Docker - standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error" raspberry

Tags: angular, linux, docker, raspberry-pi, dockerfile

I have a trouble with running container (builded ionic + angular) on raspberries (zero pi w and 4). First, I ran my container on rpi0 and I tought that it could by because its 32bit cpu, but then I tried to run my container on rpi4 and I get same error. I also tried few webservers like ngnix, apache..

Do you have any idea, how to solve this issue?

This is my Dockerfile

```
# !/bin/bash
FROM nginx:stable-alpine-perl
COPY /www /usr/share/nginx/html
```

First i built the container using this command `docker build -t ftpclient32 .`, then I run this image to create container `docker run -dit --name ftpclient32 -p 8080:80 ftpclient32` and then I did commit and push.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: What do you mean by "then I did commit and push."? Did you push your container into a registry?

Comment: @OmairMajid Yes, to hub.docker.com

Comment: I think I need more information now. You have 2 machines? A development box (where you do the container builds and then push to docker hub) and a RPi where you are looking to pull that container and run it?

Comment: @OmairMajid Exactly, I develop this code on windows 10 machine and I also builded the code and the container here. After that, I pushed it to dockerhub. Then I connect to raspberry, which should be a server and from there I pulled my container.

Comment: I think this might explain it. When you build your container on the Windows box, it builds a x86_64 (or x64, depends on what you call it) container. That container wont work on the RPi which is an aarch64 (or arm64, different names, same thing) box. Have you tried building and running it on RPi?

Comment: FWIW, `exec format error` indicates an architecture mismatch.

Comment: @OmairMajid No, I didnt.. I tought that when I pick 32bit server, that it would build container into 32bit.. But I can try it. So I should only copy builded files from angular and just build container on rpi. JS files should be platform independet..

Comment: An intel 32-bit machine and an arm 32-bit machine both use 32-bit-sized memory addressing, but they are otherwise totally incompatible.

Comment: @OmairMajid Problem when I am building container on raspberry is that I am getting timeout errors. "request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" I tried to change DNS, proxy and nothing worked.. Wierd thing is, that yesterday it worked just fine and I could pull my container that I have build on windows pc, but no, I can do nothing

Comment: also, when I run it on rpi4, everythin worked just fine, so maybe there are some hardware limitaion

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your shebang:

```
# !/bin/bash
```

there is an unnecessary space between # and !.

Use this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
```